# Can we start an android application on device start

Tags: android, android-listview

Can we start an android application on device start.Without starting the application manually

Comment: FYI since you're new.  The downvote was probably b/c the question is a duplicate and some quick searching would have revealed it.  Feel free to delete this question to remove the downvote and search in the future. :)

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked at this broadcast intent `ACTION_BOOT_COMPLETED`

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#ACTION_BOOT_COMPLETED

Check out this tutorial
http://blog.vogella.com/2011/12/11/automatically-starting-services-in-android-after-booting/

Comment: That permission needs to be given in android manifest.is it?

Comment: It is not a permission. It is a broadcast intent.